# Providing starting values for geepack::geeglm

Tags: r

Using `geepack::geeglm` with a Poisson family and identity link I’m asked to provide starting values. The documentation for the start, mustart and etastart parameters in this function refer to the glm documentation. So I was trying to use them as I would in glm. However, there seem to be differences between glm and geeglm causing some errors I could not understand.
Below is a simple reproducible example, along with the output I got (coppied as comments). Any ideas how to solve this?

```
library(geepack)

n <- 500
y= rbinom(n=500, size=1, prob=0.02)
x1 <- runif(n,0,100)
x2 <- runif(n,0,100)
x3 <- runif(n,0,100)
my_dat <- data.frame(y, x1, x2, x3)

glmfit1 <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2, data=my_dat, family=poisson("log")) # no problem
glmfit2 <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2, data=my_dat, family=poisson("identity")) # Error
# Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values
glmfit2 <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2, data=my_dat, family=poisson("identity"), start=coef(glmfit1)) # Error
# Error: cannot find valid starting values: please specify some
glmfit2 <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2, data=my_dat, family=poisson("identity"), start=c(0.5,0.5,0.5)) # Working (though with warnings)
# There were 15 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
# Warning messages:
# 1: step size truncated: out of bounds
# 2: step size truncated: out of bounds
# ...
geefit1 <- geeglm(y ~ x1 + x2, data=my_dat, family=poisson("log"), id=x3) #no problem
geefit2 <- geeglm(y ~ x1 + x2, data=my_dat, family=poisson("identity"), id=x3) # Error
# Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values
geefit2 <- geeglm(y ~ x1 + x2, data=my_dat, family=poisson("identity"), id=x3, start=c(0.5,0.5,0.5)) # Error and warnings
# Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ x1 + x2, data = my_dat, start = c(0.5,  : 
#   variable lengths differ (found for '(start)')
# In addition: There were 15 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
# > warnings()
# Warning messages:
# 1: step size truncated: out of bounds
# 2: step size truncated: out of bounds
# ...

# Trying just to see what happens:
geefit2 <- geeglm(y ~ x1 + x2, data=my_dat, family=poisson("identity"), id=x3, start=0.5) # Error
#Error in glm.fit(x = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  : 
# length of 'start' should equal 3 and correspond to initial coefs for c("(Intercept)", "x1", "x2")
```